# Future<Integer> object accepts a return type of String. How?

Tags: java, future, executorservice

I have two callable objects. one returns an Integer, and the other returns a String. I am using the ExecutorService for running them.

public class MyExecutor {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {


    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    Callable call1 = new Callable() {
        public Integer call() {
            final int a = 20;
            return a;
        }
    };

    Callable call2 = new Callable() {
        public String call() {
            return "This is a String";
        }
    };



    Future<Integer> result = service.submit(call2);
    System.out.println(result.get());

    Future<String> result2 = service.submit(call1);
    System.out.println(result2.get());

    service.shutdown();

}
```

}

As far as I know, A String cannot be cast to an integer and vice versa, however when I run the above code, result.get() perfectly prints the string, despite the result being of the Future. How is it possible? Shouldn't it give a class cast execption at runtime?

also, printing out the value of result2.get() give a class cast exception, as expected, because you can't cast an Integer to a String.

Following is the output of the above code:

This is a String

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.practice.concurrency.MyExecutor.main(MyExecutor.java:51)

Comment: `String` and `Integer` are both subclasses of `Object`... since the `Callable` are of raw type, that is, you have not specified any type, `Object` is expected

Comment: Okay, but shouldn't it go both ways? I mean if Future<Integer> prints the string because the callable is of raw, type, should't the Future<String> print the integer, and not give a class cast exception?

Comment: It’s not Future<Integer> that’s printing the String - it’s the System.out.println - and hats happy printing out the “get” result since println wants a String and that’s what it’s receiving from the Futire.  However, for result2, the println is getting an Integer from the Future so what it tries to do is cast the value it got to acStrong to print it .... hence the error.